# On-device calendar exists?

Tags: applications, samsung, calendar, 6.0-marshmallow

I am coming from iOS to my first Android (Samsung Galaxy S7) and having hard time adjusting. The first thing that is throwing me off is lack of a calendar app.

The phone came with Samsung's own S-Planner, but I wanted to use a more native android app (so that if my next phone is not Samsung, I don't have to relearn). However I cannot find anything else installed on the device. Any online search results in various 3rd party calendar apps. So, is there no such thing as a "***native* android calendar app**"?

Secondly, the 3rd party calendar apps have options of syncing to Gmail/Exchange/other accounts, but is there no such thing as "**on-device calendar**" (like on iOS)? One that isn't linked to some account online?

Thank you

Comment: most "native" apps by Google were moved to play store, like clock, map, youtube... so that it can be updated easily instead of OTA which a lot of devices don't have latest android update

Comment: find all "native" apps [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=5700313618786177705)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The native AOSP calendar app was replaced by Google's own<sup>**1**</sup>. It went by the package name `com.android.calendar`, but is no longer found in either *Google Play Store* or on *F-Droid* (you can find its code [on Github](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar), though). As for synchronization, that's usually not done by the calendar app itself but by the corresponding sync service; most calendar apps use the "calendar provider" of the Android system to store their data.

If you want a "local calendar" that's not synchronized at any cost, and your device doesn't offer such, you can e.g. use [Offline Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidwave.offlinecalendar); but that app doesn't seem to be maintained anymore (last version is from 2013).

---

<sup>**1:** See [Google’s iron grip on Android: Controlling open source by any means necessary](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/10/googles-iron-grip-on-android-controlling-open-source-by-any-means-necessary/2/)</sup>

Comment: [stand alone calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sufficientlysecure.standalonecalendar) claims to be developed from AOSP

Comment: @beeshyams it was also last updated in November 2013. This may not be a problem but it doesn't look like it will receive any further updates.

Comment: @bmdixon Noticed that and it is not truly "stand alone" going by user reviews. Was sharing as information

Comment: @beeshyams that's why I didn't mention it :) And "based upon" doesn't mean it's the same. It has a different package name for one. Some AOSP ROMs might still have it (and even maintain it), but that doesn't mean it will turn up on Play or F-Droid, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

Google Calendar could be considered as native android calendar app. You can [download it from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar). But I personally don't like it.

As for device-only calendar - I have never seen an android phone without such a calendar (I'm not familiar with Samsung devices though). Normally you can choose a calendar during creating an event.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Offline Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sufficientlysecure.localcalendar). App description says

> Lets you add calendars to the Calendar app, which are not synchronized and are accessible only on the device itself.
>   Create the calendar in this app and it will then be available in the Calendar app.

I had tried it earlier, but gave up since I found interface not very friendly (for me at least-your experience may be different). Exporting to new device could be as you would do for other apps (backing up and reinstalling) or as I see in developer reply  suggesting interface with another app to export(see 15/09/2015)

EDIT: I posted this as a comment and by the time typed the reply, found another answer (by Izzy) recommending this !